# How to put a local video to my localhost in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat

I have installed tomcat and i made a project using Swing where I record a video from my webcam and save it locally. I want to display it into my localhost using html I think ? and I have absolutely no ideea how to do this. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put this in your HTML 5:

```
<video controls>
  <source src="path/to/your/video/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="path/to/your/video/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: It does not work, error: Not allowed to load local resource

Comment: Try adding a slash before your path

Comment: otherwise you should try to use [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb)